# Force failure in restoring process of iOS 8 in app purchases?

Tags: ios, debugging, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm using non-consumable in-app purchase items for my iOS 8 app.
I would like to test what happens if a restoring process of a purchase fails. Is it possible to force that failure?

Comment: Do you want to force fail it to test your scenario of failing and retrying?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I would like to see what error messages iTunes Connect delivers.